# How to convert a char array into a FILE type in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am a C# developer so I'm a bit confused with this language. The problem here is that I'm working with someone elses code and I just need to do a slight change. I need to change a function that takes a file path parameter and uses fopen() to load it into a FILE type to a function that just takes a char array and converts that to a FILE type

How it looks right now:

```
bool ExampleFunction::Load(const string& fileName)
{
    string f = filename;


    FILE* fp = fopen(f.c_str(), "rb");
}
```

How I want it to be (pseudocode):

```
bool ExampleFunction::Load(const char* fileBytes)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(fileBytes, "rb");
}
```

Comment: `bool ExampleFunctionLoad(const char* fileBytes){ FILE* fp = fopen(fileBytes, "rb"); }` should work.

Comment: Do you want a (read-only) file stream to return the data that is in the (null-terminated?) string passed to your function?  If so, perhaps the POSIX [`fmemopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) function does what you are looking for?

Comment: Possibly an XY problem. Maybe you need a virtual class to open/close/read some bytes implemented by different subclasses.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler for some reason the "fmemopen()" function does not exist in my current set up, no clue why, even tho I included <stdio.h>. Might has something to do with POSIX but I have no clue what that is because I am not really a C++ dev. How can I get it working?

Comment: Since you've got the [tag:visual-c++] tag on the question, you may have an incomplete implementation of the POSIX API.  Alternatively, Microsoft has been known to prefix POSIX function names with an underscore, breaking POSIX compatibility but their excuse is that otherwise the name conflicts with names in the namespace reserved for users.  Try using `_fmemopen()` instead of `fmemopen()`.  If that doesn't work either, put it down to "incomplete POSIX implementation" and use something else.  There's a chance there is a Microsoft function that does the equivalent job — but I don't know its name.

Answer (score 0):

Your so-called 'pseudo' code actually already is the correct function – apart from that you do not return a value. Just some further hints:

- If you store the file pointer in a member variable, check if a file has already been opened *before* and close it if need be.
- If you just load some data from file into local variables, don't forget to `fclose` the file again *afterwards*.

Otherwise you get a memory leaks.

However, inside your original function, you create a totally useless **copy** of the input string:

```
bool ExampleFunction::Load(const string& fileName)
{
    string f = filename; // <--- copy!!!

    FILE* fp = fopen(f.c_str(), "rb");
}
```

Either use the paramter directly:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
```

or, if you want a shorter alias, create it as reference again:

```
 string const& f = filename;
 // alternatively:
 auto& f = filename;
 //  ^ don't forget, otherwise copy again
```

I personally would recommend to keep original function as overload:

```
bool ExampleFunction::Load(char const* filename);
bool ExampleFunction::Load(std::string const& filename)
{
    return Load(filename.c_str());
}
```

so that users having stored the file name in a `std::string` object can use that one directly.